# How to bulk assign random authors to posts on custom post type?

Tags: wordpress

I want such a thing that searched over and over but nothing found!
I have about 15 authors and imported +1000 posts from my previous website. And all of them are submitted for one and same author. But I need to assign posts to random authors.
Is there any functions, plugin , etc to doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
$posts = get_posts([
  'posts_per_page' => -1 //retrieve all posts
]);

$users_ids = [1,2,3]; //replace with the desired user id's

foreach($posts as $post){

  $arg = [
    'ID' => $post->ID,
    'post_author' => array_rand($users_ids), //random user ID
  ];

  wp_update_post($arg); 

}
```

In the example above I'm pulling all the posts (of a post type post), if you need to do it only on specific posts, you'll have to change the `get_posts()` arguments to get specific post id's or range of post id's

Answer (score 1):

1. Get all the necessary users
2. Get the posts you need
3. Update authors to posts

```php
$users = get_users( ['fields' => 'ID'] );

$posts = get_posts( [
    'post_type'      => 'your_custom_post_type',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields'         => 'ids',
] );

foreach ( $posts as $post_id ) {
    wp_update_post( [
        'ID'          => $post_id,
        'post_author' => array_rand( $users ),
    ] );
}
```